# How to extend Navigation in CSS

Tags: css

I have a div which in 1000px; and a navigation bar which is also 1000px; but it doesn't extend as much as the div.

Please help...

[index.html]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<title>[phantzm]</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<center>
<div class="banner">
<IMG SRC="logo.png" class="logo" WIDTH=100 HEIGHT=100 ALT="pZ">
</div>
<center>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="navMenu">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#">fun stuff</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">jokes</a></li>
<li><a href="#">riddles</a></li>
<li><a href="#">facts</a></li>
</ul><!-- end of Second List -->
<li>
<a href="#">   my work   </a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">   my favourite songs   </a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">   my favourite links   </a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">   about me   </a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">   contact me   </a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">phone</a></li>
<li><a href="#">e-mail</a></li>
<li><a href="#">mail</a></li>
</ul><!-- end of Second List -->
</li>
</li><!-- end of List Item -->
</ul><!-- end of Unordered List -->
</div><!-- end of navMenu div -->
</div><!-- end of wrapper div-->
</center>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFCECE">
</body>
</html>
```

[style.css]

```
body {
    background: SILVER;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 auto;
}

.banner {
   background: blue;
   width: 1000px;
   height: 70px;
}
.logo {
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-right: 500px;
}

#navMenu {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   line-height: 30px;
   width: 1000px;
}

#navMenu ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 1px white;
}

#navMenu li:hover {
    font-weight:normal;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    background:silver;
}

#navMenu ul li {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style:none;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   background: #4B8EE0;
   border: 1px white;
   border-left: 1px solid #0000ff;
    border-right: 1px solid #000ff;

}

#navMenu ul: hover {
   text-transform: capitalize;

}

#navMenu ul li a {
   text-align: center;
   font-family: "Arial";
   text-decoration: none;
   height: 30px;
   width: 150px;
   display: block;
   color: white;
}

#navMenu ul ul {
   position: absolute;
   visibility: hidden;
   top:30px;
   border: 1px white;
}

#navMenu ul li:hover ul {
   visibility: visible;
}
```

I have added the code for the style and index.. As you can see both the banner and navmenu have 1000px;

Comment: Show your code and HTML. We can't see your screen from here.

Comment: If you place your code here or a www.jsfiddle.net would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change you CSS like this: [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bAwwq/)

```
#navMenu ul li {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style:none;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   background: #4B8EE0;
   border: 1px white;
   border-left: 1px solid #0000ff;
    border-right: 1px solid #000ff;
    width:165.6px;
}
```

165.6 is (1000 - 5)/6 (approx)

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome, right-click each element and choose "Inspect Element". Scroll down to "Metrics". This will show you what other properties are affecting the apparent width of each element (margin, border, padding, box-model, and positioning).

Answer (score 0):

The navigation is not 1000px because each item is set to fixed width

You should change the width of each item using percentage, so the width of each item is relative to 1000px and the number of items

however, if it's still not working, you should add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` at the bottom of `<ul></ul>`

Answer (score 0):

The length of the navigation bar is decided by each individual bullet point in the list. Where you have `width: 150px;` shows the length of each individual `li`. The length of all of them together gives you the length of the navigation bar. You add `display: inline-block;` under the `#navMenu ul li` to make it depend on the original width.